# Using a SeekBar within a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, seekbar

I have a seekbar in a listview, it is disabled to stop the user from changing the value whilst scrolling the list. I wish to enable it if the list item is long clicked, allow the user to change it and then disable it again.

Any suggestions.

I seem unable to access the seekbar from the activity as it is setup inside the ArrayAdapter to display a value from the database

I am able to fire a both a click event and a long click event for the list item, as the seekbar is currently disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

In the ArrayAdapter I set both enabled and focusable to false and added the SeekBar listener, setting the attributes to false allowed me to use the list item onItemClicked listener. Inside the onItemCLickListener I retreived the seekbar, set the attributes to true, this meant it could be slid up or down. I then disabled it after the adjustment had been made. code below

### ArrayAdapter Snippet

this code is inside the creation of the list item, in which the seekbar is housed

```
    seekBar.setClickable(false);
    seekBar.setFocusable(false);
    seekBar.setEnabled(false);

    /* attach listener */
    attachProgressUpdatedListener(seekBar, positionOfItemInList);
```

### AttachProgressUpdatedListener

this method attaches the listener to the seekbar, inside the arrayAdapter class

```
private void attachProgressUpdatedListener(SeekBar seekBar,
    final int position) {

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
    int task_id = (Integer) seekBar.getTag();

    TaskHandler taskHandler = new TaskHandler(DBAdapter
        .getDBAdapterInstance(getContext()));

    taskHandler.updateTaskProgress(task_id, progress);

    mList.get(position).setProgress(progress);

    //need to fire an update to the activity
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    seekBar.setEnabled(false);

    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // empty as onStartTrackingTouch listener not being used in
    // current implementation

    }

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // empty as onProgressChanged listener not being used in
    // current implementation

    }
});

}
```

### OnItemCLickListener

this snipped is from the activity which houses the list view.

```
taskListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seek);
    sb.setFocusable(true);
    sb.setEnabled(true);

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Luke , How do you have a ListView reference **mList** inside of ArrayAdapter class?

Comment: @AlexSanchez I'll check and get back to you. Might be a while as I'm on holiday at the moment.

Comment: Really great answer. Saves lots of time.

Comment: @Smeet - let me know if you have any improvements, i found clicking on the seekbar to enable it was much better than risk repositioning sliders when scrolling up/down the list

Answer (score 0):

I had overcame this issue by setting the following attributes to the `seekbar` in `listview` item layout file. Then I had the `click` event of `listitem` and `seekbar` working.

```
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/playback_icon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```