# How to set progress of seekbar in listview with value mentioned in the database?

Tags: android, listview

I am populating a listview with textviews and seekbars using simple cursor adapter.I could able to map the textviews with values from database, and I want to set the progress of seekbar with the database values. Can someone help me providing the approach with sample snippet?

I also want to get the progress of seekbars in the listview and save it back to database.

I used below code:

```
String[] strFieldName=new String[]{Database.NAME};
int[] Ids=new int[] {R.id.seekName1};
SimpleCursorAdapter planSCA=new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    getActivity(),
    R.layout.layout_seekitem,
    cursor,
    strFieldName,
    Ids
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your query,

> [This is for using seekbar with listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340771/using-a-seekbar-within-a-listview)
>
> [For accessing the DB to get value of progressbar in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398561/how-to-get-the-value-for-each-seek-bar-created-in-list-view-android)

Comment: Please include relevant parts of the linked content in the answer, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers